# How to recognize the function call in a dynamic lib?

Tags: arm, dynamic-linking

when I disassemble an OpenCV dynamic library file (`libopencv_imgproc.so`), I find that there are a lot of `bl` instructions which target address are in the `.plt` section. But, I could'n find its symbol info.

```
00110ee0 <cvResize>:
  110ee0:   b5f0        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
  110ee2:   4603        mov r3, r0
  110ee4:   b0bf        sub sp, #252    ; 0xfc
  ...
  110ef4:   4ca8        ldr r4, [pc, #672]  ; (111198 <cvResize+0x2b8>)
  110ef6:   9500        str r5, [sp, #0]
  110ef8:   f70e ebda   blx 1f6b0 <_init+0x2b4>
  ...
```

I could not find the address `1f6b0` in the `.text` section. It actually is in the `.plt` section. However, I couldn't find it in the symbol table.
How can I get these missed symbol info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it the hard way:

1. disassemble the target PLT stub and figure out what pointer it's using. E.g.:

   ```
   359dc:  e28fc601    add ip, pc, #1048576    ; 0x100000
   359e0:  e28ccaa2    add ip, ip, #663552 ; 0xa2000
   359e4:  e5bcf900    ldr pc, [ip, #2304]!    ; 0x900
   ```

   Here, the `ip` will be: `0x359e4+0x100000+0xa2000 = 0x1D79E4`, so the last `LDR` will dereference `1D79E4+0x900 = 0x1D82E4`.
2. look up the address in the list of relocs (`objdump -dr`):

   ```
   001d82e4  00005216 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   _ZN2cv10cvarrToMatEPKv
   ```

Doing it the easy way:

1. Just use IDA :), or at least a newer `objdump` [which knows about PLT stubs](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2004-04/msg00469.html).

   ```
   000359dc <_ZN2cv10cvarrToMatEPKvbbi@plt>:
   ```

Please note that `objdump` relies on the fact that the order of PLT stubs usually matches the order of relocations in the PLT reloc list. In theory, one can patch a PLT stub after linking so it uses another symbol's pointer.